# Higher Order functions as a property of an object in Javascript

Tags: javascript, higher-order-functions

Why do I get an makeAdder is not a function error here?  And how can I accomplish making a property of my Widget object a function that is returned from a higher order function?

```
    var Widget = { 
           init: function() { 
           var total = this.add2(3); 
           console.log(total); // expect 5
        }, 
        add2: this.makeAdder(2),  
        makeAdder: function(left) { 
          return function(right) { 
             return left + right; 
          };
        }
    };

Widget.init();
```

Comment: you can't define it mid-literal without a getter or named function. append the prop after you close out the literal.

Comment: Use ES6 classes if you want a syntax similar to this

Comment: Are you getting the error trying to define the "Widget" variable, or trying to invoke "init"?

Comment: While attempting to invoke Widget.init()

Comment: *"While attempting to invoke Widget.init() "* - Really? You should be getting the error when declaring `Widget`, because `this.makeAdder()` doesn't exist. (Note that whether `makeAdder()` is a higher order function or not is not relevant here. The problem is that the `Widget` object doesn't exist until after the whole object literal is evaluated, and `this` doesn't refer to `Widget` at that point.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can't find the function as it's not been defined yet.

In `add2: this.makeAdder(2)` you're calling the function 'makeAdder', not defining it while `Widget` is still being defined.

Try moving the `add2` to later in the process, eg:

```
var Widget = { 
    init: function() { 
        this.add2 = this.makeAdder(2);
        var total = this.add2(3); 
        console.log(total); // expect 5
    }, 
    makeAdder: function(left) { 
      return function(right) { 
         return left + right; 
      };
    }
};
```

Comment: This is how i'm current'y handling the problem,and this works, I was wondering if there were a more explicit way to set that property in the literal, maybe with a Setter?

Comment: You can't refer to properties of an object in the process of creating it, because the object doesn't exist until you finish creating it.

Answer (score 0):

@freedomm-m answered my question best in terms of how I presented it.  My Collegue suggested currying, in order to accomplish what I was looking for.  I'll include it in case anyone is looking to do something similar.

```
var Widget = { 
  init: function() { 
    var total = this.add2(3); 
    console.log(total); 
  }, 
  add2: function(val) { 
    return this.add(2)(val);
  },  
  add: function(left) { 
      return function (right) {
        return left + right;
      }
  }
};

Widget.init();
```

Comment: This will break if i do : 
var b = {};
b.add3 = Widget.add2;
b.add3()